# CHECK statement only IF the condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have to create a table where I need to check a condition only if another condition is met.

To precise I have a table "repair" with columns "solved" and "price", if the column "solved" has value 0 i need to check that the column "price" is equal to 0 too.

How can I do this in the create table statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
ALTER TABLE Repair
ADD CONSTRAINT MyConstraint CHECK((Solved = 0 AND Price = 0) OR (Solved <> 0 AND Price <> 0));
```

> How can I do this in the create table statement?

```
CREATE TABLE Repair(
  Solved BIT NOT NULL,
  Price DECIMAL(19,4) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT MyConstraint CHECK((Solved = 0 AND Price = 0) OR (Solved <> 0 AND Price <> 0))
);
```